# WPF, DoubleAnimationUsingPath, how set targetproperty?

Tags: wpf, animation, path

I want to animate canvas after path and now use:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translateYAnimation, new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty));
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translateYAnimation, new PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty));
```

Can I set Canvas **center** property? I don't want the ellipse to move outside the path...

image: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Canvas.Center property. So no, you can't set that.

You need to do your animation path based on it being the upper left corner (or whichever corner you want, really). Not the center.

Edit: I suppose there's lots of ways around that... you could probably write your own attached property for Center that you animate and have it set the Top/Left based on the current Height/Width. Just as an example. But the point is, you've got to do something to make it work.